# Read dataframe from an empty cell and start data init

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I've a database with missing values in the `siret` column. I'd like to read and append data **scraped** from google. It looks like:

[image: yth]

I've a for loop in which I want to read the `Nom` column then concatenate it with `complement_word`; this'll give me `keyword`.
I'll search this keyword on google then extract a specific number to add to the `siret` column (`results[0]['siret']`).

I tried this which is not working.

```
start_time = time.time()

compt = 0
for i, keyword in enumerate(liste_partenaire.Partenaire):
    if liste_partenaire.siret[i] == '':   # here I want to start reading and adding data
        keyword = keyword+ ' ' + 'infogreffe '+ str(liste_partenaire.complement_word[i])
        compt+=1
        print('loading... ',round(compt/len(liste_partenaire.Partenaire)*100, 2), '%',end="\r")
        try:
            results = scrape_google(keyword, 1, "fr")
            for result in results:
                if results:
                    liste_partenaire['siret'][i] = results[0]['siret']
                else:
                    liste_partenaire['siret'][i] = ''
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error in results:: [ {} ]'. format(e))
    finally: 
        time.sleep(2)
    
print("--- %s seconds d'éxecution ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? If you are getting an error, show the traceback. If you are getting a value that you don't expect, show that value and what you'd like to get.

Comment: I dis not start from the empty field of siret but from the row 0.